# Continuously print last line of file to single line on terminal

Tags: tail

How can I continuously print the last line of a file to a *single* line in the terminal?

The following works, but has a high performance hit.

```
while true; do tail -1 /tmp/somelog | tr "\012" "\015"; done
```

Comment: `sleep` in the loop, assuming the update frequency isn't too high.

Comment: @nohillside: Yup, I thought about that.

Answer (score 5):

`tail` already has a `-f` (`--follow`) option to poll files for appended content - the trick is to prevent the output from being buffered when you add a pipe to do the line ending replacement:

```
tail -n1 -f /tmp/somelog | stdbuf -o0 tr '\n' '\r'
```

For a discussion of the buffering issue see for example [Piping tail -f into awk](https://superuser.com/questions/742238/piping-tail-f-into-awk)

Comment: Interesting! However, this doesn't seem to work here. I'm on a BSD variant (macOS), so I had to install `coreutils` for `stdbuf`, but I get no output in the terminal when appending data to the log. Is there any way to make this work with, or preferably without `stdbuf`?

Comment: @forthrin sorry I don't know - let's see if any MacOS / BSD specialists can shed light on it

Comment: Seems to work nicely out of the box on Debian. However, there is the pesky issue where lines longer than the terminal cause flooding. How can I make `stdbuf` take `cut -c 1-$(tput cols) | tr '\n' '\r'` as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Use `watch`:

```
watch -t -n0.2 tail -n 1 /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

-t turns off the title

-n is the refresh interval